# Sketch: Broken Combined shape export to SVG?

Tags: svg, sketch-app

I'm trying to export some vector art made by composing Ovals. When I exported my art first time everything had gone fine. After few changes in other Layers in my file (the picture shown is a part of the bigger scene) I tried to export again and had got the following picture. Notice the glitchy cut brush bundles at the left bottom and top.

I guessed first that this SVG file is somehow broken and that it is just a rendering issue of Chrome. After digging into SVG code using Chrome dev tools I find out that the combined shapes are exported as SVG paths. It looks like Sketch processes combined layers and generate path (form) improperly.

How could I deal with this issue and export SVG properly or revert back my changes in the file?

[image: How it looks in Sketch][image: How SVG looks like in Chrome]

Comment: What is the size of these elements in sketch? Ultimately yes, it's safer to flatten complex elements before exporting to SVG.

Answer (score 0):

I just spent hours trying to fix this problem and finally the only solution was to replace Ovals with Paths. It required to outline those ovals manually.

After doing that combined shapes have been exported properly.